# How should I use maxlength in CFQUERYPARAM list="true"?

Tags: list, coldfusion, maxlength, cfml, cfqueryparam

I'm curious how the maxlength attribute works in CFQUERYPARAM when you are passing a list. Does the maxlength apply to the length of the entire list (i.e. length of "1,2,3,4,5,6" = 11)? Or does the maxlength apply to each item in the list?

I cannot find any documentation of this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the answer, and it's what I expected and wanted. Maxlength applies to each item in a list, so the following works:

```
<cfqueryparam list="true" value="1,2,3,4,5,6" maxlength="1" />
```

whereas, the following throws an exception:

```
<cfqueryparam list="true" value="1,2,3,4,5,26" maxlength="1" />
```

Exception:

> "The cause of this output exception was that:
>   coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryParamTag$InvalidDataException: Invalid data
>   value 26 exceeds maxlength setting 1.. "

Comment: Wish this was documented by Adobe. Now it's document here!

Comment: Well written response with error message and a very simple example to understand the error.

Comment: Please use `cfqueryparam` with `cfsqltype` attribute.